# Internal Server Error Regarding ElementHelper.php.bak

Tags: updates

I am getting the following error on my local machine when updating Craft 2.6.

> /craft/app/helpers/ElementHelper.php.bak: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I don't even see that file in the directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

At what point of the update process are you getting that error?

During an auto-update, Craft creates a `.bak` of every file that it's about to update before doing the file swap.  The last step of the update process (the "Cleaning up..." stage), goes through and deletes all of the `.bak` files that were created.

I'd also make sure that the `craft/app` folder is recursively writable by PHP as that's required for auto-updating to work correctly.